# jframe does not fit on the window

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

I was wondering how to set a JFrame to open up full screen in netbeans. I currently do this

Code:

```
this.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

But some components in my frame end up off the screen. Its not working too well at all. I would like the components to all scale down so that on screens with lower resolutions the frame still fits all its parts in. [image]

Comment: If you are using NetBeans' default layout manager, GroupLayout, you may be better off not using it and instead use other layout managers that are more tolerant of application re-sizing. For more detail on this, consider posting an image of your current GUI as you desire it to be seen.

Comment: YOu have right. i think the problem is on the use of the GroupLayout manager. I have tried everything but still some components on jframe are being cropped. if i try to change the layout manager everything is falling apart.

Comment: @Steven, why? The purpose of the setExtendEdState() method is so you don't have to worry about all that. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 2):

If your components don't show up on the JFrame, maybe you can try:

```
frame.pack();
```

And if you really want to go Full Screen, you can use:

```
frame.setUndecorated(true);
```

I hope this works.